# How to wait for a thread to finish in asynchronous code

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio

I have a telegram bot written on aiogram. And the function which accepts a button press has a sub-thread, in which for loop bypasses the array, creates the final message and send it back to function **callback_query_keyboard**:

```
def create_message(response, out_queue):
    message = ''

    for i in response:
        message += f'• <a href="{i.get("link")}">{i.get("article")}</a>\n\n'

    out_queue.put(message)



@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def callback_query_keyboard(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    out_queue = queue.Queue()

    connection = db.DbConnection()
    await connection.create_pool()
    response = await connection.get_data(callback_query.data)

    Thread(target=create_message, args=[response, out_queue]).start() #funciton create_message is run

    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, text=f'{out_queue.get(block=False)}', parse_mode='HTML', disable_web_page_preview=True)
```

The problem is in the fact, that after the **thread** is started the funciton continues working and when the interpreter reaches the line where user recieves a message nothing happens and before the thread is completed the bot stops responding. I fixed this mistake by adding **await asyncio.sleep()**:

```
    Thread(target=create_message, args=[response, out_queue]).start()

    await asyncio.sleep(0.2)  <--

    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, text=f'{out_queue.get(block=False)}', parse_mode='HTML', disable_web_page_preview=True)
```

But I think it's not the best practise:

1. The function doesn't work if thread works more than 0.2 seconds
2. The programm idles waiting for the excess time to tick

**Question:**
How to change **await asyncio.sleep(0.2)** on something better or how to rewrite this part of code?

Answer (score 0):

That is the working solution for the problem:

```
def create_message(response):
    message = ''
    for i in response:
        message += f'• <a href="{i.get("link")}">{i.get("article")}</a>\n\n'
    return message

@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def callback_query_keyboard(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await connection.create_pool()
    response = await connection.get_data(callback_query.data)

    message = await asyncio.to_thread(create_message, response)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, text=message, parse_mode='HTML', disable_web_page_preview=True)
```